# MYSQL updating a table containing a join and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to SQL, i am trying to update monthly salary based on employees working for a certain duration, the query displays the data using info from the person and employee table but it won't update, i keep getting a 'operand should contain 1 column' error? How would i go about displaying all the data and be able to update the monthly_salary column as well? Thanks.

```
 UPDATE employee ep set monthly_salary = monthly_salary*1.15 = all(
    SELECT p.person_id, p.name_first, p.name_last, ep.monthly_salary, ep.start_date, curdate() as today_date,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,ep.start_date,curdate()) as duration_months 
    FROM employee ep
    INNER JOIN person p ON ep.person_id = p.person_id having duration_months > 24);
```

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NglMX.png)

I want this expected result but the monthly salary hasn't been updated yet, is it possible to display this and update the monthly_salary?

Comment: It isn't possible to do a select and an update in a single statement, you need two separate queries for that.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to do both in a single query. Typically one would run a "select query" to inspect if the desired logic appears correct, e.g.

```
SELECT
        p.person_id
      , p.name_first
      , p.name_last
      , ep.start_date
      , curdate() as today_date
      , TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,ep.start_date,curdate()) as duration_months 
FROM employee ep
INNER JOIN person p ON ep.person_id = p.person_id 
WHERE ep.start_date < curdate() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH
;
```

In that query the important piece of logic is the `where clause` which seeks out any employees with a start date earlier than today - 24 months.

If that logic is correct, then apply the same logic in an "update query":

```
UPDATE employee ep 
SET monthly_salary = monthly_salary*1.15 
WHERE ep.start_date < curdate() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH
;
```

Syntax notes:

- you cannot string multiple conditions together using multiple equality operators (`monthly_salary = monthly_salary*1.15 = all(...)` *there are 2 = signs in that*
- `x = all()` requires that all values returned by a subquery will equal x
- the `having clause` is NOT just a substitute for a `where clause`. A having clause is designed for evaluating aggregated data e.g. `having count(*) > 2`

Finally, while it was inventive to use the having clause, what you were doing was gaining access to the alias 'duration_months', so you could simply have done this instead:

```
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,ep.start_date,curdate()) > 24
```

**BUT** this is not a good way to filter information because it requires running a function on every row of data before a decision can be reached. This has he effect of making queries slower. Compare that to the following:

```
WHERE ep.start_date < curdate() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH
```

`ep.start_date` is not affected by any function, and `curdate() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH` is just one calculation (not done every row). So this is much more efficient (also known as "sargable").